# Какой PostgreSQL пароль для входа по умолчанию (win10)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Подскажите какой пароль PostgreSQL для входа. Никак не могу войти.

PostgreSQL 15 версии

устанавливал cinst -y postgresql
запустил "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\pg_env.bat"
запускаю psql , просит пароль.

Пароль в системе у меня нет. (win10)

psql: ошибка: подключиться к серверу "localhost" (127.0.0.1), порту 5432 не удалось: ВАЖНО:  пользователь "user" не прошёл проверку подлинности (по паролю)

Comment: логин postgres пароль postgres попробуй

Comment: пробовал это и 1234 и 12345 так же пробовал менять пароль юзера под которым в системе net user user 12345 - тоже не работает!

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от такого какую сборку под Windows вы использовали для установки сервера. По моему мнению лучший выбор это сборки от [EDB](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads). При установке  этот пакет запросит у вас пароль для пользователя postgres.

ЗЫ:

В некоторых браузерах не отображаются ссылки для загрузки под Windows пишет:

> Not supported

В этом случае пробуете другой браузер, как выяснил в Яндексе работает.

Если сервер уже развернут и нет желания его переустанавливать (для повторного получения запроса пароля пользователя придётся удалить сервер и кластер или переименовать кластер на период переустановки), то можете поступить следующим образом:

1. Остановить службу postgresql-x64-ХХ - PostgreSQL Server ХХ
2. Найти в каталоге сервера файл pg_hba.conf
3. в строке:

> host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256

заменить scram-sha-256 на trust

5. Запустить службу
6. Зайти без пароля и установить пароль как кой вам нужно:

   SET password_encryption =  'scram-sha-256';

   ALTER ROLE postgres PASSWORD 'mypassword';
7. Откатить изменения файл pg_hba.conf
8. Перезапустить службу.